# Create wcf self host application that will act like windows service and also as restful server?

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

Is it possible to create self host wcf application that will expose restful web service and also will act like windows service ( will start on machine start ) ?

Comment: Just make it a Windows Service.  A Windows Service can host a RESTful web service.

Comment: 10x - i can't find any example of windows service that is a host of wcf application

Comment: You're search engine must be broken then :)  [How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: something that i don't understand maybe ... the client that will get use the Restful service - will connect to which port ? he can connect to the default port 80 like if the host is the iis ?

Comment: You may need to specify a different port, since if you have IIS on the same machine it may be holding onto Port 80. I'm not sure though.  In any event, you can specify the port to use when you start the Service Host.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost/

Comment: FYI, you don't need ASP or IIS to create a restful web service: for instance, a Console or a WinForms application can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host a WCF service using a windows service and then it is accessible via an HTTP request(as long as ports open, etc)

Just create your WCF library and and a windows service project to the solution.

Then edit the static class program usually in program.cs
to host the service.

```
static class Program 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
       /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new WCFService() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting RESTful services in a Windows service, have you considered self-hosting ASP.NET Web API using TopShelf?

http://codeopinion.com/self-host-asp-net-web-api-as-a-windows-service/